# Como juntar campos de uma array php

Tags: php, sql, json, array

Boa noite, então estou enfrentando um problema com uma array, minha ideia é o seguinte, criar uma array `$MESA[IDMESA]` e dentro dessa array eu teria todas informações sobre uma determinada mesa que é identificada com a variável `$json[IDCARTAO]` porém meu inner join retorna os dados separados da seguinte maneira:

```
{
    "IDTICKET": 714,
    "NOMEFANTASIA": "ABOBORA",
    "PRECO": "3.5000",
    "IDCARTAO": 3537
}{
    "IDTICKET": 714,
    "NOMEFANTASIA": " ALCOOL EM GEL",
    "PRECO": "5.5900",
    "IDCARTAO": 3537
}{
    "IDTICKET": 714,
    "NOMEFANTASIA": "ABS.ENLACE GE.M.S.C\/AB.",
    "PRECO": "2.0000",
    "IDCARTAO": 3537
}
```

Minha ideia é pelo denominador comum que é o `IDTICKET`, ou seja, ficaria:

```
MESA[IDMESA]{
    "IDTICKET": 714,
    "NOMEFANTASIA": "ABOBORA",
    "PRECO": "2.0000",
    "NOMEFANTASIA": "ABS.ENLACE GE.M.S.C\/AB.",
    "PRECO": "3.5000",
    "NOMEFANTASIA": " ALCOOL EM GEL",
    "PRECO": "5.5900",
    "IDCARTAO": 3537
}
```

Ele agruparia todos produtos na mesma array, porem eu não estou conseguindo de forma alguma pensar em como fazer, eu pensei ao invés de usar um inner join eu usaria um cross join, segue meu código abaixo

```html
<?php

  header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
  $json = array();
  $db = 'localhost:C:\baseking\TGA.FDB';
  $username = 'SYSDBA';
  $password = 'masterkey';

  $con = ibase_connect($db, $username, $password);
  $sql = "SELECT TTICKET.idticket, TTICKETPROD.codprd, TPRODUTO.NOMEFANTASIA, TPRODUTO.preco1, TTICKET.idcartao from tticket
  inner join TTICKETPROD on (TTICKETPROD.idticket = TTICKET.IDTICKET)
  inner join TPRODUTO on (TTICKETPROD.codprd = tproduto.codprd)where TTICKET.status = 'A' 
  ORDER BY TTICKET.idticket ASC, TTICKETPROD.codprd ASC";
  $rc = ibase_query($con, $sql);
  while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($rc)) { 
      
     // print_r($row);
   // echo json_encode($row);
 /*   foreach ($row as $resultado=> $valorresultado) {
         $result['CODPRD'][ $resultado -> IDTICKET] = $valorresultado;
         echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }*/
   $result['IDTICKET'] = $row -> IDTICKET;
    $result['NOMEFANTASIA'] = $row -> NOMEFANTASIA;
    $result['PRECO'] = $row -> PRECO1;
    $result['IDCARTAO'] = $row -> IDCARTAO;
    $json['MESA'] = $result; 
    echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


     // echo "".$json['CODPRD'];
    }

  /*if($json['CODPRD']){
    $string = implode(",",$json['CODPRD']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM TPRODUTO where CODPRD = '{$string}'";
    $rc = ibase_query($con, $sql);
    while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($rc)) { 
      $json['NOMEFANTASIA'][] = $row -> NOMEFANTASIA;
      echo json_encode($json['NOMEFANTASIA']);

    }  */

  ibase_free_result($rc);
  ibase_close($con);
?>
```

A ideia inicial que eu tive, seria usar um loop e um if, que ficaria da seguinte maneira

```
for( i = $result['IDTICKET]; i < NUMEROS DE LINHAS QUE TEM; i++)
if($result['IDTICKET'][i] == $result['IDTICKET'][i]){

  //AQUI NESSA CONDIÇÃO ELE PEGARIA TODOS DADOS DE LINHAS QUE TEM O IDTICKET
}
```

Porem eu ainda não conheço a sintaxe de php a fundo e não sei como fazer isso dentro da linguagem, desde já fico muito grato.

@EDIT
Então funcionou parcialmente, para pegar os dados diretamente do select

```
$foo = [  $json['MESA']];
$mesas = [];
foreach ($foo as $value) {
  $mesas[$value['IDTICKET']][] = $value;
}
```

porem a forma que ele mostra os dados na consulta não ficou tão estruturado

```html
 (
    [714] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [IDTICKET] => 714
                    [NOMEFANTASIA] =>  ALCOOL EM GEL
                    [PRECO] => 5.5900
                    [IDCARTAO] => 3537
                )

        )

)
{
    "IDTICKET": 714,
    "NOMEFANTASIA": "ABS.ENLACE GE.M.S.C\/AB.",
    "PRECO": "2.0000",
    "IDCARTAO": 3537
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua ideia está quase certa, você não precisa fazer um `if` basta você criar um novo `array` para agrupar por `IDTICKET` passando como índice do `array`, assim os dados com o mesmo id serão agrupados.

```
$foo = [
    [
        'IDTICKET' => 714,
        'NOMEFANTASIA' => 'ABOBORA',
        'PRECO' => '3.5000',
        'IDCARTAO' => 3537
    ],
    [
        'IDTICKET' => 714,
        'NOMEFANTASIA' => 'ABOBORA',
        'PRECO' => '3.5000',
        'IDCARTAO' => 3537
    ],
    [
        'IDTICKET' => 714,
        'NOMEFANTASIA' => 'ABOBORA',
        'PRECO' => '3.5000',
        'IDCARTAO' => 3537
    ],
    [
        'IDTICKET' => 714,
        'NOMEFANTASIA' => ' ALCOOL EM GEL',
        'PRECO' => '5.5900',
        'IDCARTAO' => 3537
    ],
    [
        'IDTICKET' => 714,
        'NOMEFANTASIA' => 'ABS.ENLACE GE.M.S.C\/AB.',
        'PRECO' => '2.0000',
        'IDCARTAO' => 3537
    ]
];

$mesas = [];
foreach ($foo as $value) {
    $mesas[$value['IDTICKET']][] = $value;
}

// Print do resultado
echo '<pre>';
print_r($mesas);
die;

// Resultado:
Array
(
    [714] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [IDTICKET] => 714
                    [NOMEFANTASIA] => ABOBORA
                    [PRECO] => 3.5000
                    [IDCARTAO] => 3537
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [IDTICKET] => 714
                    [NOMEFANTASIA] => ABOBORA
                    [PRECO] => 3.5000
                    [IDCARTAO] => 3537
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [IDTICKET] => 714
                    [NOMEFANTASIA] => ABOBORA
                    [PRECO] => 3.5000
                    [IDCARTAO] => 3537
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [IDTICKET] => 714
                    [NOMEFANTASIA] =>  ALCOOL EM GEL
                    [PRECO] => 5.5900
                    [IDCARTAO] => 3537
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [IDTICKET] => 714
                    [NOMEFANTASIA] => ABS.ENLACE GE.M.S.C\/AB.
                    [PRECO] => 2.0000
                    [IDCARTAO] => 3537
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: @MatheusMartins não precisa pedir desculpas, a gente tá aqui pra ajudar.
Não consegui entender muito bem esse comentário, se você puder alterar a pergunta e tentar explicar melhor.